# Is it possible to limit the maximum number of children a div can have?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drag-and-drop

So I want to limit the number of children a `div` can have.

The idea is that you have a `selected commands div` where you can drag and drop whichever commands (essentially buttons) are available to you at any given time, from another `div` called `available commands`, but only up to a maximum of four at a time.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v9Fg8/2/

How can I limit the number of maximum possible children this `div` can have, so that when it reaches 4, one of the children gets replaced on the `drop` event.

Comment: So what child do you want to remove? Any?

Comment: @dfsq: Either the one you decide to drop on top of, or the first one in the list (so that the new one goes to the end of the list).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check if the container has too many elements and save the parent element when dragging like this

```
function drag(ev) {
    itemParent = ev.target.parentElement;
    //console.log(itemParent);
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
};

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    if (ev.target.childNodes.length == 4) {
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        console.log(itemParent);
        itemParent.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    } else {
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/v9Fg8/4/)

**with jQuery**

```
function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    if ($('.commands').not(itemParent).children().length == 4) {
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        console.log(itemParent);
        itemParent.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    } else {
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        $('.commands').not(itemParent).append($('#' + data));
        //ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
};
```

This code is better, so you can drop the elements on elements so you don't append to the boxes.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/v9Fg8/5/)

Answer (score 1):

It can be super simple with `getElementsBtClassName`:

```
var dropped = document.getElementById('selected').getElementsByClassName('button');
```

and inside drop handler you just check `dropped.length`:

```
function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));

    // Check number of children
    if (dropped.length > 4) {
        ev.target.removeChild(dropped[0]);
    }
};
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/v9Fg8/6/

Comment: Yes this seems to be it; However, I wanted the element removed from the top box to reapper on the bottom box when there are already 4. I wanted to swap elements, not have them disappear.

Should I just append the `dropped[0]` to the available div before removing it from the selected div?